# Android - Best pratice to repeat a task in the background even if the screen is locked

Tags: android, notifications, task

What is the best way to repeat a task on android with a short period (for example 2 seconds)? It must keep running even if the screen is locked. If I am not mistaken only the AlarmManager can be used for it because it wakes up the phone from sleep but it should not be used for such a short period (recommended minimum 1 minutes) because it drains your battery and uses too much resource. So what type of notification tool is used by chat programs like Facebook Messenger or Skype to keep the user notified in every second of a day?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: they are using some kind of [push notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging)

Answer (score 1):

> So what type of notification tool is used by chat programs like
>   Facebook Messenger or Skype to keep the user notified in every second
>   of a day?

They use the concept of push notification. Basically there is a service running in the background which listens to the server for any new data. When server has a new data it 'pushes' it to the client and the service handles the data and displays it as a notification.

If you're a beginner then you should look into [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/) as a starting point for implementing push notification.

Answer (score 0):

this is one option to you,check may be helpful

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code which you want to repeat
    }
}, start_task_after_some_milli_seconds, repeat_time_in_milli_seconds);
```

When you want to stop
then call `timer.cancel()` method

Comment: I saw some articles about timertask where they say we shouldn't use it because it leaves memory holes and makes strange runtime errors. When I used it I also had errors but when I replaced it with handler and runnable the problems disappeared. But unfortunately timertask and runnable stop functioning when the device goes into sleep mode so my program doesn't notify.

Comment: then can you create persistent service and in that call timer.